# enumerate instances in R and add a new column

Tags: r, date, sorting, calculated-columns

I have a table:

```r
dt <- data.table(instance = c("A","A","A","B","B","B", "C","C","C","C","C","A","A",
    "B","B","B", "C","C","C","C","C"), 
   date = c("2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25",
   "2019-02-25", "2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25","2019-02-25",
   "2019-02-25","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01",
   "2019-03-01", "2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01","2019-03-01"), 
 y = c("0,1","0,2","0,2","0,1","0,1","0,15","0,1","0,2","0,3","0,1","0,1",
   "0,1","0,1","0,1","0,25","0,3","0,1","0,1","0,15","0,1","0,2")
dt
```

I need to add a column "N" in which instances will be ordered from 1 to max number of instances for currency (here maximum number is 5 (number of rows with currency RON)).
And all types of currency should be enumerated from 1 to this maximum number. And if there is smaller number of variables for some currencies it should add rows where values for column "N" will be missing Na.

So, I need a code after which I could get the following table:

```
| instance | date | y  | N|
:-----|-----| ------|-----|
| A | 2019-02-25 | 0,1 |1|
| A | 2019-02-25 |0,2  |2|
| A | 2019-02-25 |0,2  |3|
| A | 2019-02-25 |Na   |4|
| A | 2019-02-25 |Na   |5|
| B | 2019-02-25 |0,1  |1|
| B | 2019-02-25 |0,1  |2|
| B | 2019-02-25 |0,1  |3|
| B | 2019-02-25 |Na   |4|
| B | 2019-02-25 |Na   |5|
| C | 2019-02-25 |0,1  |1|
| C | 2019-02-25 |0,2  |2|
| C | 2019-02-25 |0,3  |3|
| C | 2019-02-25 |0,1  |4|
| C | 2019-02-25 |0,1  |5|
...
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity for `tidyr::complete`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat  |>
    group_by(currency, date)  |>
    mutate(N = row_number())  |>
    ungroup()  |>
    complete(currency, date, N) |>
    arrange(date, currency, N)

# # A tibble: 30 x 4
#    currency date           N y    
#    <chr>    <chr>      <int> <chr>
#  1 EUR      2019-02-25     1 0,1
#  2 EUR      2019-02-25     2 0,2
#  3 EUR      2019-02-25     3 0,2
#  4 EUR      2019-02-25     4 NA
#  5 EUR      2019-02-25     5 NA
#  6 RON      2019-02-25     1 0,1
#  7 RON      2019-02-25     2 0,2
#  8 RON      2019-02-25     3 0,3
#  9 RON      2019-02-25     4 0,1
# 10 RON      2019-02-25     5 0,1
# # ... with 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `rle` function provided in `base` r like so:

```
instances = rle(dt$currency)

dt$N = unlist(sapply(instances$lengths,function(x) 1:x))
```

RLE stands for run-length encoding. The function returns the data value and counts of successive occurrences or each 'run' of values in a vector. Once we have this we access the counts through the `lengths` element of `instances`.